# why is the last tag being hidden?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts stock to implement the diagram and I have problems that the last note on the Y-axis is hidden (see screenshot).

At the same time, it is present in DOM. I've tried different ways and different implementations of the option, but all without success.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the `yAxis.showLastLabel` option:

```
  yAxis: {
    showLastLabel: true
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/okch38rw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.showLastLabel